# why is PHP not throwing a parse error?

Tags: php

There are lots of "Why does PHP throw an error here?" questions. Well, this is a little different. I found the following code while reworking some code written by a coworker:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {http://google.com/
  echo $value;
  // ...
}
```

My first thought: "Umm...how embarrassing; he must have accidentally pasted that in there..." followed by: "Wait...there's no way this code actually runs...that should be a syntax error". And yet:

```
 $ php -l test.php
 No syntax errors detected
```

And indeed, (like so much PHP code that seemingly shouldn't run) it runs in production without trouble. So I did a little testing:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {http://google.com/ <-- original, no error
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {http: <-- also no syntax error
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {http  <-- bingo! "Unexpected T_ECHO..."
```

What little tidbit of PHP's grammar is producing such strange results?

(I am using PHP 5.3.5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `http:` is being interpreted as a label (which are used for [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.goto.php) statements), and the `//google.com/` as a comment (which can easily be seen through syntax highlighting).

[Documentation on goto](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.goto.php):

> The goto operator can be used to jump to another section in the program. **The target point is specified by a label followed by a colon**, and the instruction is given as goto followed by the desired target label.

Comment: `http:` is a label, and `//` is a comment. I've seen this trick before.

Comment: Ugh. Another item on the "why the *hell* did this dismal feature have to be implemented in a language that is already ridden with dumb features?" list.